# scala compare fields of case class and collect the diff

Tags: scala, diff

**For two instances of one case class, need to compare all fields and collect the list of diff properties.**

Say the case class is like this:

```
case class People(name: String, age: Int, sex: Option[String] = None)
```

To compare

```
val john = People("john", 20)
val tom = People(sex = Some("m"), age = 20, name = "tom")
```

Expected

```
def func diffPeople(left, right) = ???

diffPeople(john, tom) == List("name", "sex")
```

#### Requirement

- In my case there are almost 50+ properties so the code is required to be as compact as possible.
- Can't use reflection, as the comparison is in Production environment and latency/memory restricted, and ideally don't require a third-party library like shapeless.

Comment: **Shapeless** doesn't add any overhead in runtime but whatever, there are probably libraries that do this like https://diffx-scala.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but whatever, if you want a simple solution all you need to do is use `produictElementNames` & `productIterator` and couple of `zip` and a `collect`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I should read more about shapeless and thank you for pointing it out there is no runtime overhead. Just changed my wording above.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Runtime behavior of methods written with Shapeless can be very different. For example this implementation of `ZipWithKeys` works at runtime in `O(n)` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/HvNqC1EnQzW0oECDROzsTg while this implementation works at runtime in `O(1)` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/HvNqC1EnQzW0oECDROzsTg/1 Implicits are resolved at compile time but type-class instances are instantiated at runtime.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez There is (almost) no runtime work only if a type class works only on type level i.e. its instances are defined with `null` right-hand side: `implicit val inst: TC[A] = null`.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I have found personal best function so far is to use `productElementNames` and `productIterator` ([Scala docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.5/scala/Product.html)) to iterate field names and values:

```scala
/** @param left: the first case class instance
  * @param right: the second case class instance
  * @return a string list of unmatched fields
  */

def diffPeople(left: People, right: People): List[String] =
  if (left eq right) List.empty
  else {
    left.productElementNames
      .zip(left.productIterator.zip(right.productIterator))
      .collect { case (field, pair) if pair._1 != pair._2 => field }
      .toList
  }
```

More generical version ([Try on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/EdZuebxpSKG0VvI7w5iGhA/4)):

```scala
def diff[P <: Product with AnyRef](left: P, right: P): List[String] =
  if (left eq right)
    List.empty
  else
    left.productElementNames
      .zip(left.productIterator.zip(right.productIterator))
      .collect { case (field, (l, r)) if (l != r) => field }
      .toList
```

Comment: `props` can be derived using `productElementNames` - The `==` will already compare property by property so you are not saving anything with that early check, but the opposite; you may use `eq` tho. - You don't want to use `toList` to avoid materializing unnecessary data - That `foldLeft` is better expressed as a `collect`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Excellent! Your comment is very valuable and I have refactored to a new version to include your points. Let me know if you have new thoughts.

Comment: That version looks pretty good, I would just do two minor adjustments. First, in the `collect`, you may do this instead: `case (field, (l, r)) if (l != r) =>` which is IMHO a bit clearer _(feel free to use better names than `l` & `r`)_. Second, I would make the method generic like `def diff[P <: Product](left: P, right: P): List[String] =`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I have added generic version and get a small new question. In order to do `left eq right`scala requires `AnyRef | Null`. But we already define `P <: Product` which extends from `Any`. So I have to remove the first `left eq right` which is fine for my case. My question is that is it possible to still keep the eq check?

Comment: Oh yeah `eq` needs `AnyRef` and it is weird that `Product` doesn't extend that, anwyays, you can do this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/EdZuebxpSKG0VvI7w5iGhA/4